# Is there any way to get the Cognito username in AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, amazon-cognito

As far as I can tell, there is no way for an AWS Lambda function to look up a username of my Cognito users (I am using UserPools).

This seems extremely strange as I would have thought that applications everywhere depends almost always on manipulating the username.

I have been successful in getting the Cognito IdentityId but I can't see any way to relate the IdentityId to anything that looks up the Cognito User that the IdentityId relates to.

Is there any way of getting the username?  What is the relationship between IdentityId and username?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue???? Let me know if the solution I provided helps you, I use it on every project & it would be cool to get some feedback on how it works for others, if at all.

Comment: @lopezdp that project was 3 years ago I don't really recall.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled to find an answer to this problem for a while because there just aren't any concise responses on any of these threads online.

It sounds like you're trying to come up with an effective `Authorization` strategy after the user has `Authenticated` their credentials against your Cognito User Pool using custom attributes.

I created a library that I use to export a few functions that allow me to capture the `UserPoolId` and the `Username` for the **authenticated** user so that I can capture the `custom:<attribute>` I need within my lambda so that the conditions I have implemented can then consume the API to the remaining AWS Services I need to provide authorization to for each user that is **authenticated** by my app.

Here is My library:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
// ensure correct AWS region is set
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-2"
});

// function will parse the user pool id from a string
export function parseUserPoolId(str) {
    let regex = /[^[/]+(?=,)/g;
    let match = regex.exec(str)[0].toString();

    console.log("Here is the user pool id: ", match);

    return match.toString();
}

// function will parse the username from a string
export function parseUserName(str) {
    let regex = /[a-z,A-Z,0-9,-]+(?![^:]*:)/g;
    let match = regex.exec(str)[0].toString();

    console.log("Here is the username: ", match);

    return match.toString();
}

// function retries UserAttributes array from cognito
export function getCustomUserAttributes(upid, un) {
    // instantiate the cognito IdP
    const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
        apiVersion: "2016-04-18"
    });

    const params = {
        UserPoolId: upid,
        Username: un
    };

    console.log("UserPoolId....: ", params.UserPoolId);
    console.log("Username....: ", params.Username);

    try {
        const getUser = cognito.adminGetUser(params).promise();
        console.log("GET USER....: ", getUser);
        // return all of the attributes from cognito
        return getUser;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR in getCustomUserAttributes....: ", err.message);
        return err;
    }
}
```

With this library implemented it can now be used by any lambda you need to create an authorization strategy for.

Inside of your lambda, you need to import the library above (I have left out the import statements below, you will need to add those so you can access the exported functions), and you can implement their use as such::

```
export async function main(event, context) {
  const upId = parseUserPoolId(
    event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider
  );
  // Step 2 --> Get the UserName from the requestContext
  const usrnm = parseUserName(
    event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider
  );
  // Request body is passed to a json encoded string in
  // the 'event.body'
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  try {
    // TODO: Make separate lambda for AUTHORIZATION
    let res = await getCustomUserAttributes(upId, usrnm);

    console.log("THIS IS THE custom:primaryAccountId: ", res.UserAttributes[4].Value);
    console.log("THIS IS THE custom:ROLE: ", res.UserAttributes[3].Value);
    console.log("THIS IS THE custom:userName: ", res.UserAttributes[1].Value);

    const primaryAccountId = res.UserAttributes[4].Value;

  } catch (err) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log("This call failed to getattributes");
    return failure({
      status: false
    });
  }
}
```

The response from Cognito will provide an array with the custom attributes you need. Console.log the response from Cognito with `console.log("THIS IS THE Cognito response: ", res.UserAttributes);` and check the index numbers for the attributes you want in your CloudWatch logs and adjust the index needed with:

`res.UserAttributes[n]`

Now you have an `authorization` mechanism that you can use with different conditions within your lambda to permit the user to POST to DynamoDB, or use any other AWS Services from your app with the correct authorization for each authenticated user.

In the response that you can see in `res.UserAttributes[n]` you will see the attribute for **sub** which is what you are looking for.

Comment: parseUserName gives me the 'sub' uuid, which does not allow me to get the user with getAdminUser. (ERROR in getCustomUserAttributes....:  User does not exist.) Is there some setting I missed?

Comment: @pivu0 yeah, you missed the rest of the solution. you have to see the second half of the code to see how I use them, the first half of the code is the different functions needed.

Pay attention to how I use it with: await getCustomUserAttributes(upId, usrnm);

Comment: furthermore, if the user does not exist, maybe you should create/register a user in your Cognito instance. this is to be used with user's who have already registered so you can get the custom attributes needed...

Comment: @pivu0 you need to pass the paras object with that sub data into: cognito.adminGetUser(params).promise();

Comment: I did not miss anything, and implemented as you showed. It was cognito.adminGetUser(params).promise() that threw this error. The user is registered, if I use the actual username (I hardcoded the username to test) instead of the sub I will find it. 

Anyway, I have found somewhere that if I use federated identities you can't find a user with just the sub.

Comment: the sub is returned in the response from cognito.adminGetUser(params)

not sure what youre doing, I use that implementation across every project I deploy.

the data will be in an array sub is usually in the first index [0]...

Comment: The parseUsername returns exactly the same string as the 'sub' of the user. So the sub is then passed as the username later on in your code.

Comment: not really sure what youre trying to do right now... I use this to get the custom attributes I need out of the users whom I have registered in Cognito. what is it that youre trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

I got user details in lambda after adding Cognito Authorizer in Api gateway which gives decoded `Authorization` token passed in header in `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims` object.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the JWT token from the Authorization header and then decode it with some library for your language.

In the payload of the JWT is the username.

Or you can call `listUsers` on `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property) with a filter of the `sub` that you get in `{...}authorizer.claims.sub`.

Comment: I need to get this at the back end.  Can your suggestion be done at the back end?

Comment: @DukeDougal My suggestion is for the backend. Look at the Authorization header in the backend. It is an encoded JWT token that you can decode and look into. Contains useful data.

Comment: Agreed with the Authorization header. Call `listUsers` with a filter doesn't seem like it would scale well.

Answer (score 2):

elaborating on @doorstuck's answer, If you are using Lambda invoked by APIG with AWS_IAM Authorization. Then, you can get the username and other attributes as follows:

The event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider  is a string that looks like

"cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_xxxxxxx,cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_xxxxxx:CognitoSignIn:SSSSSSSS"

The SSSSSSSS is the sub of the user in User Pool. You can easily decode the string to get the sub and use it in the filter of listUsers.

Example:

```
const provider = 
event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider;
const sub=provider.split(':')[2];
const Params = {
     UserPoolId: 'xxxxxxxxx', /* required */
     Filter: "sub=\""+ sub + "\"",
     Limit: 1
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(Params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else   console.log(data.Users[0].Attributes);       
});
```

The data includes useful information about the returned user where data.Users[0].Attributes has all your user attributes.
The result is

```
[ { Username: 'xxxxx',
Attributes: [Object],
UserCreateDate: 2017-09-12T04:52:50.589Z,
UserLastModifiedDate: 2017-10-24T01:50:00.109Z,
Enabled: true,
UserStatus: 'CONFIRMED' } ] }
```

data.Users[0].Attributes is

```
[ { Name: 'sub', Value: 'SSSSSSS' },
{ Name: 'address', Value: 'xxxxxxxxi' },
{ Name: 'email_verified', Value: 'true' },
..... ]
```

Note that you can also filter the returned attributes by using

```
AttributesToGet: [
    'STRING_VALUE',
    /* more items */
  ],
```

in Params.

Comment: Wouldn't the `listUsers` call query the entire user-base on each request? I'm not sure how that would scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you front your Lambda function with API Gateway you can use the Cognito Authorizer to authenticate your User Pools tokens directly and pass in the username extracted from the token via **$context.authorizer.claims.preferred_username**

More details on this integration is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Answer (score 0):

We can manipulate context in body mapping template also to get the sub (username) and it works fine for me. Try out this rather than splitting in you lamda function.

```
 #set($sub = $context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider.split(':')[2])
{
"tenantId": "$sub"
}
```

Comment: After trying various things - this works for me - in python zappa

`from flask import request`
`request.environ.get('lambda.event').get('requestContext').get('identity').get('cognitoAuthenticationProvider')`

`cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-xxxxxxxx,cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-xxxxxx:CognitoSignIn:xxxxxxx-86d4-4cb0-bedb-xxxx`
 last bit is the username of the cognito user that is logged in